# Change of the keyboard language and operating system language on users' computers using GPO (Windows Server)

Tags: windows, server, windows-server-2019

Hello Stack Overflow community!

I am responsible for managing a fleet of computers in my organization, and I would like to know how to configure the change of keyboard language and operating system language on users' computers using Group Policy Objects (GPO) in a Windows environment.

Could someone please help me understand the steps and best practices for this process? Are there any specific recommendations or pitfalls I should be aware of?

Could someone please help me understand the steps and best practices for this process? Are there any specific recommendations or pitfalls I should be aware of?

Thank you very much for any guidance and advice on this task.

I've tried searching online for a solution, but it hasn't been helpful, and I can't seem to find a straightforward GPO for language changes. I already have the additional ADMX files downloaded.

I also came across information suggesting that I need to install an additional language pack, but it wasn't explained how this would help, and I couldn't find any information on it either.

I've read that PowerShell scripts may be an option, but I don't have much information on how to proceed with that.

Comment: This question is better answered in ServerFault: https://serverfault.com/tour

Comment: alright, thnaks!